# What is the role of "Using the laboratory" in "Using the laboratory you can ..."

Tags: grammaticality

Or grammatically correct sentence on bottom.

> Using the laboratory you can filter picks by differents parameters and
>   find a best strategy for you.

If I correct understand the top sentence is compound:
1. Using the laboratory you can filter picks by differents parameters 
2. find a best strategy for you.

The first sentence have the subject you *and*  the predicate *can* and it this sentence is active voice.

My question is or correct is use part `Using the laboratory` in begin of sentence but not as example

> You can filter picks using the laboratory by differents parameters

or

> You can filter picks by differents parameters using the laboratory

What part of sentence is : `using the laboratory`?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I'm sorry to tell you this but we don't do proofreading here. There are many sites on the internet where you can get help with proofreading.  If you have a **specific question** about the grammar of this sentence that we can answer, please [edit] your question to refer to it and explain what you're confused about.

Comment: Both *by different parameters* and *using the laboratory* are [adverbial clauses](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_clauses.htm) (syntactically optional [adjuncts](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adjuncts.htm)). They can be in either sequence (and we could add more such elements, such as *tomorrow, once you know how, easily,* etc.).